# NullPointerException on listview.getCount() method

Tags: android-listview

Application crashes throwing `null` pointer exception on line  `RoomList.getAdapter().getCount()`.
I need to fetch each edit Text value from `listview` and apply some computations on it, after searching various posts, I have found out this solution but it is not working properly.

```
RoomList = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list2);
for (int i = 0; i < RoomList.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
        View view = RoomList.getChildAt(i);
        EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editRoom);
        Log.d("value from each edit text", edit.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have NPE because `RoomList.getAdapter()` returns `null`. Maybe you didn't call [`RoomList.setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29).

By the way, you should change the name `RoomList` to `roomList`, to stick to Java [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). `RoomList.getAdapter()` at first glance looks like a static method call of some `RoomList` class.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion.I misaligned my code , now NPE is thrown for EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editRoom) , what else is wrong here?

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.editRoom)` returns `null`, which means that `R.id.editRoom` was not found in the XML layout which you have set with a `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_which_must_have_editRoom_id)`. You can also regenerate `R.java` file by cleaning the project, `Project` > `Clean...` to make sure that `R.java` is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are accessing your list's adapter without first setting it.

```
RoomList = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list2);
RoomList.setAdapter(new SubClassOfBaseAdapter()); // <-- setup your adapter here, with anArrayAdapter or a sublass of BaseAdapter
for (int i = 0; i < RoomList.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    View view = RoomList.getChildAt(i);
    EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editRoom);
    Log.d("value from each edit text", edit.getText().toString());
}
```